# Tweet value prediction: What sort of analysis (Bayesian?) might predict how much a Twitter user will value a tweet?

Tags: java, scala, twitter, bayesian

I’m thinking of adding a feature to the [TalkingPuffin](http://TalkingPuffin.org) Twitter client, where, after some training with the user, it can rank incoming tweets according to their predicted value. What solutions are there for the Java virtual machine (Scala or Java preferred) to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this *well* is not easy.  Google would love to be able to do such things ("What links will the user value"), as would Netflix ("What movies will they value") and many others.  In fact, you'd probably do well to read through the notes about the [winning entry for the Netflix Prize](http://www.netflixprize.com//community/viewtopic.php?id=1537).

Then you need to extract a bunch of features, as @hmason says.  And then you need an appropriate machine learning algorithm; you either need a function approximator (where you try to use your features to predict a value between, say, 0 and 1, where 1 is "best tweet ever" and 0 is "omg who cares") or a classifier (where you use your features to try to predict whether it's a "good" or "bad" tweet).

If you go for the latter--which makes user-training easy, since they just have to score tweets with "like" (to mix social network metaphors)--then you typically do best with support vector machines, for which there exists a [fairly comprehensive Java library](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/).

In the former case, there are a variety of techniques that might be worth trying; if you decide to use the LIBSVM library, they have variants for regression (i.e. parameter estimation) as well.

Answer (score 8):

This is a classification problem, where you essentially want to learn a function y(x) which predicts whether 'x', an unlabeled tweet, belongs in the class 'valuable' or in the class 'not valuable'.

The trickiest bits here are not the algorithm (Naive Bayes is just counting and multiplying and is easy to code!) but:

1. Gathering the training data
2. Defining the optimal feature set

For one, I suggest you track tweets that the user favorites, replies to, and retweets, and for the second, look at qualities like who wrote the tweet, the words in the tweet, and whether it contains a link or not.